# How to select a line from a osm shape by osm_id

Tags: openstreetmap, cartography, tilemill

I'm using TileMill to make a map, but I can't seem to be able to format a specific item with a specific `osm_id` via `mss`.

I have a shapefile added as a layer `#line`:

[image]

Then, in the `features` list of `#line`, I can see the different `osm_id`s:

[image]

The problem is how can I format a specific line or element with a specific `osm_id` via the mss editor.

I tried this to make a very thick boundary lines for the city of Medellín:

```
#line[osm_id='1343264']{
  line-color:#555555;
  line-width:40;
}
```

and

```
#line[osm_id='1343264']{
  line-color:#555555;
  line-width:40;
}
```

As you can see, the element exists in OSM: http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/1343264

AND it also exists in the `#line` shapefile I'm using. The osm_id in TileMill is the same, but with a minus sign in front.

How can I select this boundary line via mss to format it?

Answer (score 1):

OSM relations are stored in the Postgis database with negative id to distinguish them from ways that could have the same id. So you have to put that negative osm_id value into your style definition.

Apart from that, you could as well look into the polygon table. Relations of type boundary or multipolygon that form a closed line should land there (unless the line is not closed by accident).

If I load the relation into my postgis database, I get two entries in the lines table and one in the polygon table. The line is closed, but the relation members don't have the same orientation. That's why there are two features in the line table.